# adjust water level in toilet flush

Tags: toilet, flushvlave

I have inherited a toilet (pictured). In the tank, the level -- to which the water currently fills -- is indicated by the red arrow. There's an old water-level stain at a much higher level (green arrow) which seems to be the level to which the water used to fill at a prior time.

It appears that the flush-valve system was replaced at some prior time, and the water started filling to the lower level (red arrow)

Currently, the amount of water per flush is lower than I prefer, and I would like to raise the water level back to the original level (green arrow).

**My question:** is it possible to adjust the flush-valve system to do this, or will I need a new flush-valve system. If the latter, your advice on something I can easily get from Menards / Lowes / Amazon will be appreciated.

Tank brand: Mansfield,
No. 160,
Bush Valve Model 211

Current Flush-Valve brand: Korky

[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking up the model number you have online? I'd start there...try to find an installation brochure or manual. I am almost certain any of these will have a way to adjust the level.

Comment: Might have a valve for low flush.  Most toilet fill valves use a adjustable float valve, where the water raises the float to turn off the fill water.  Not sure about your valve.

Comment: @crip659 I would say all toilet valves have fill level adjustment

Answer (score 9):

I found some instructions here:

Unclip the refill tube from the overflow tube.

Rotate the float (the silver part) 1/8 turn counterclockwise to unlock it.

Move it up or down to raise or lower the water level respectively.

Turn it 1/8 clockwise to lock it in place.

Clip the refill tube on the overflow tube.

[Fill level adjustment](https://toilethaven.com/2020/05/28/toilet-float/)

Comment: @thanks_in_advance - Note that you have the "internal float" style.

Comment: Please use the voting system if you like the question or answers.

Comment: @MichaelKaras thank you for reminding me, just upvoted the question